# NControl draw method not firing

Tags: c#, xamarin, custom-controls

I've recently discovered the NGraphics & NControl libraries available to use along side Xamarin.Forms, and it seems great so far.

The problem I'm having is that the draw method never gets called, and I'm not too sure where I'm going wrong. My code is below (I've stripped out all the unnecessary bits), any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public class CustomGrid : NControlView
    {
        public CustomGrid ()
        {
            base.Invalidate (); //Invalidating the control doesn't redraw the control
            Content = new Label {BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent};
            BackgroundColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Blue;
        }


        public override void Draw (NGraphics.ICanvas canvas, NGraphics.Rect rect)
        {
            base.Draw(canvas, rect);
            //foreach column draw the grid line on the right
            foreach (CustomColumn c in ColumnCollection) 
            {
                canvas.DrawLine (c.CoOrds.startX,c.CoOrds.startY, c.CoOrds.EndX, c.CoOrds.EndY,Colors.White);
            }

            //for each row draw the bottom grid line
            foreach (CustomRow r in RowCollection) 
            {
                canvas.DrawLine (r.CoOrds.startX,r.CoOrds.startY, r.CoOrds.EndX, r.CoOrds.EndY,Colors.White);
            }
        }

        public List<CustomColumn> ColumnCollection { get; set; }
        public List<CustomRow> RowCollection { get; set; }


    }
```

Just to ensure I wasn't going crazy, I copied and pasted the example found on the [NControl GitHub Repo](https://github.com/chrfalch/NControl/blob/master/NControlDemo/NControlDemo.FormsApp/Controls/RoundedBorderControl.cs) and that doesn't seem to work either.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: If you minimize the application or move it off screen, and then bring it back does the drawing work?

Comment: On which platform are you testing?

Comment: Testing on Andorid using Xamarin Player (Nexus 4) - Using the menu button to select a new app and then coming back to the app does not fix it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you call `NControlViewRenderer.Init()` after `Forms.Init()`
2. In `public override void Draw(NGraphics.ICanvas canvas, NGraphics.Rect rect)` you do not necessarily need to call `base.Draw()`
3. Try calling `CustomGrid.Invalidate()`, that should force a redraw
4. Make sure your control is actually on screen, within the view port and has a size bigger then 0,0, you could give it a pink background and see if that shows up anywhere...
5. Why do you say *it seems great so far.* when it clearly doesn't? Like, what part is actually working then?
6. Set a break point in your subclass' ctor and see if it actually gets instantiated...

Did any of these help?

Comment: Number one did the trick. I read through that documentation so many times I have no idea how I missed it.